# is the hp business notebook 8510p adequate to run Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

It's the 8510p2221207, with Intel Core 2 Duo @2.2GHz, 2GB memory and 120GB HDD. The hard drive size is totally adequate for me. Best Buy is selling it for $186, refurbished. I want to load the latest LTS version of Ubuntu. This is a 2007 machine. I will visit web pages to read info, watch YouTube, check email, use Open Office, and watch DVDs both on the notebook and on a TV feed by the notebook via HDMI cable. Is this notebook capable of doing that?  Thanks.
Also, can somebody mail me a CD with the latest LTS ISO image? I just heard about Lubuntu. I've used 12.04 LTS and 13.04 in the past and liked both of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop meets the Ubuntu minimum hardware requirements, so it will run office tasks at acceptable speed. Problems may arise with DVD and TV support - those activities depends on GPU also, which is probably very weak in your case. It does not mean, that watching movies will be impossible, but stuttering may occur.

You can try one of the lightweight Ubuntu versions like [Xbuntu](http://xubuntu.org) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.org), but from my experience, they are slightly less user-friendly than default Gnome version, and don't not make significant difference in the performance.